# Using CloudDeploy for the following expression

Tags: cloud-deploy

There is a simple code for the dynamic version of `Classify` for notable persons

```
i = Dynamic[img = CurrentImage[]; 
{img,Classify["NotablePerson", img, {"TopProbabilities", 3}]}]
```

how can I use `CloudDeploy[]` for this expression?

I tried :

```
CloudDeploy[i,Permissions -> "Public"]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Does a non `Dynamic` version works when evaluated in cloud notebook? (Can not check as I don't have a web camera).

Comment: @Kuba [not work](http://imgur.com/NddEaX4) `CloudDeploy[
 Classify["NotablePerson", CurrentImage[], {"TopProbabilities", 3}]]`

Comment: First of all this evaluates locally and is deployed after that. Go to the browser and open a notebook or use `Delayed`. Additionally this works, it just doesn't know how to display found entities.